# What does "Don't hate" mean or imply here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, slang

I am not quite get the logic between the lines here. Is **"Don't hate"** a slang or sth? Why did Bruce say it? (he sure knows Tony not hates him, so it's a joke, right? but meaning what?) This phrase bothers me a lot, and **I am looking for a paraphrase or replacement of this sentence.**

**The context is**: Tony Stark is trying to persuade Bruce Banner to help design artificial intelligence by using the scepter with the mind stone.

**Here is the sentence**:

> “Down in Strucker’s lab, I saw some fairly advanced robotics work.
>   They deep-sixed the data, but I’m guessing he was knocking on a very
>   particular door.”
>
> “Artificial intelligence,” Bruce said.
>
> “This could be it, Bruce. This could be the key to creating Ultron.”
>
> Bruce looked at Tony. “I thought Ultron was a fantasy.”
>
> “Yesterday it was,” Tony said. “But if we can harness this power . . .
>   apply it to the Iron Legion protocol . . .”
>
> “That’s a man-size if.”
>
> “Our job is if. What if you were sipping margaritas on a sun-drenched
>   beach? Turning brown instead of green? Not looking over your shoulder
>   for Veronica.”
>
> **“Don’t hate,”** Bruce said. “I helped design Veronica.”
>
> “As a worst-case measure. What about a best case? What if the world
>   was safe? What if the next time aliens roll up—and they will—they
>   couldn’t get past the bouncer?”
>
> *The Avengers II*

Answer (score 1):

It is slang, but the meaning is fairly literal: don't act hatefully towards me.

It's often said humorously, where *hate* is a much stronger word than would be appropriate. In this more jocular context, the meaning is more like, "don't be rude."